# Can you use the Typewriter Visual Studio plugin in a Windows Class Library?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, class-library

There is a Visual Studio plugin called Typewriter that helps produce TypeScript files from C# files.  I am doing this so I can have similar model classes on the front end of a web application as well as the back end.  The back end portion needs to be a windows class library.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the .tst cannot find the source files.  in the template constructor 
             settings.SetMappedSourceFile = file => 'path to files to be converted'

This seems to solve the problem